# Read Write headers Rest Controller

Tags: spring, rest

Is/how possible to access the HttpRequest headers in a Rest controler method and can that header be directly written?  I am sending the subscriber choice off a select to the a REST method from an Ajax call, just cant interpret or find any example on how to access in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the incoming headers. Simply use

```
@RequestHeader("the-header-name") TheHeaderType theHeader
```

as a parameter in the controller method, or

```
@RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers
```

to get many headers at once.

However, I'm not sure what this is asking:

> can that header be directly written?

Comment: @cp. based on the edit you've suggested to my answer, you're writing javascript and not java, so this question should not have been tagged as "spring"

Comment: It is a combination, client-side Ajax to get the data to a Spring Boot application with a REST endpoint.  It works as a Spring application if the @RequestHeader is removed, however that is not the use case and I am nonplussed to how to achieve the intent.  I thank you for your suggestion, I will pursue that more throughly, or any other.

Answer (score 0):

To my chagrin found the answer [here](https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax/issues/35).  It is in the Ajax call as of 1.5.